# Netlify background function returns after it (Done executing background function handler-background)

Tags: javascript, netlify, netlify-function

My code in local works fine, but in Netlify it doesnot. Iam not sure whats happening. The flow is I generate invoices using easy invoice package and trying to upload it to s3 in async. But my code executes on the netlify platform wierdly.

```
generating invoice...
called in
◈ Done executing background function handler-background [here it actually exits, i think]
called out
```

My code is like this:

```
const generateInvoice = async (data) => {
  let  base64FileString = '';
 
      try {

        console.log("called in")
        base64FileString = await createInvoice(data); (---> this is creating problems, internally it returns a promise)
        console.log("called out")
      } catch(e) {
        console.log("Cannot create invoice ==> ", e)
        return;
      }

    return base64FileString.pdf;
  }
};
```

At the output, you can see the `called in` 
is printed and then it exits
`◈ Done executing background function handler-background` 
and again after some time, it print
`called out`

This happens only on `netlify function:serve` (i.e) dev environment

But in Netlify platform it stops at the   `called in`

Some help is appreciated.

Normal invoke of this function works properly (i.e) `node <filename>`

Any javascript issue here??

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I was having multiple `await` calls inside a loop. Using `Promises.all(<loop code goes here>)` and instead of `forEach` for looping using `map` solved the issue.

Also If I was having a callback function in between on a Promise based approach. Changing that to promise cleared the issue.